# searching a nested javascript object, getting an array of ancestors

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, nested

I have a nested array like this:

```
array = [
    {
        "id": "67",
        "sub": [
            {
                "id": "663",
            },
            {
                "id": "435",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "546",
        "sub": [
            {
                "id": "23",
                "sub": [
                 {
                     "id": "4",
                 }
             ]
            },
            {
                "id": "71"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to find 1 nested object by its id and get all its parents, producing an array of ids.

```
find.array("71")
=> ["546", "71"]

find.array("4")
=> ["546", "23", "4"]
```

What's the cleanest way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Can the same Id appear in your structure more than once?

Comment: Use recursion to walk down the tree and build the parent list each iteration.

Comment: What's your goal with this type of data-structure? It feels like you're going to have to loop through everything to get what you want.

Comment: @rwilliams nested categories.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Recursively:

```
function find(array, id) {
  if (typeof array != 'undefined') {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (array[i].id == id) return [id];
      var a = find(array[i].sub, id);
      if (a != null) {
        a.unshift(array[i].id);
        return a;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = find(array, 4);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/VBJqf/

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this - [jsonselect.org](http://jsonselect.org).

**EDIT**: I've just had a play with JSONSelect and I don't think it's appropriate for your needs, as JSON does not have an intrinsic 'parent' property like xml.

It *can* find the object with the matching id, but you can't navigate upwards from that. E.g.

`JSONSelect.match(':has(:root > .id:val("4"))', array)`

returns me:

`[Object { id="4"}]`

which is good, it's just that I can't go anywhere from there!

Comment: Thanks, I really don't think this is the way to go, it's a rather large library for something simple

Comment: Yes I understand and I agree! I just thought I'd edit my answer with the reasons why I didn't think it was appropriate in case folk wanted to see my reasoning :)