# Path to matching key value pair in a nested object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to implement a search in a nested object.

```
   // Returns an array of matching objects
    function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
        var objects = [];
        for (var i in obj) {
            if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
            if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
                objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
            } else if (!$.isNumeric(obj[key]) && i == key && obj[key].toLowerCase().match(val)) {
                objects.push(obj);
            }
        }
        return objects;
    }
```

This function returns the matching object on basis of key value pair provided.

What I want is the path to the object where key value pair is found.

Sample data

```
TestObj = {
    "Categories": [{
        "Product1": [{
            "id": "a01",
            "name": "Pine",
            "description": "Short description of pine."
        }, {
            "id": "a02",
            "name": "Pine",
            "description": "Short description of pine."
        }, {
            "id": "a03",
            "name": "Poplar",
            "description": "Short description of poplar."
        }],
        "id": "A",
        "title": "Cheap",
        "description": "Short description of category A."
    }, {
        "Product2": [{
            "id": "b01",
            "name": "Maple",
            "description": "Short description of maple."
        }, {
            "id": "b02",
            "name": "Oak",
            "description": "Short description of oak."
        }, {
            "id": "b03",
            "name": "Bamboo",
            "description": "Short description of bamboo."
        }]
    }]
};
```

I was trying to write a function

```
function objPath(obj, key, val, path) {
    var result = [];
    var passName = '';
    if (path) {
        passName = path;
    }
    var tempArray = [];
    for (var prop in obj) {
        var value = obj[prop];
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            tempArray = objPath(value, key, val, passName);
            $.each(tempArray, function (k, value) {
                result.push(value);
            });
        } else if (prop == key && obj[key].toLowerCase().match(val)) {
            result.push(obj[key]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

If I call function as

```
objPath(TestObj, 'id', 'b03');
```

Which should return  `Categories > Product2 > 3rd Row`

But all I'm getting is the key. How to fix the `objPath` function to obtain required result

Comment: Care to make me aware why a negative?

Comment: i was going to ask the same question (i hate downvotes without explanation -if someone has an issue, be helpful is my motto). anyway, i have pinged you a +1 as i think this is a fair question.

Comment: I think it's because you've not actually explained what your **issue** is, and what not saying what output you are receiving.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? What exactly should the function return, a string? If it now returns the matching object, should it not do that anymore (because you can't return two things at the same time)?

Comment: my gut feel is that being a recursive function, you must be hitting some overflow somewhere and bailing before the return.

Comment: @Juhana I have added code of what I have started so far. Since this could be something generic I thought someone should have already tried this.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381332/searching-a-nested-javascript-object-getting-an-array-of-ancestors ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have wrote a custom function

```
function objPath(obj, key, val, path) {
    var result = [];
    var passName = '';
    if (path) {
        passName = path;
    }
    var tempArray = [];
    for (var prop in obj) {
        var value = obj[prop];
        if (typeof value === 'object') {
            tempArray = objPath(value, key, val, passName);
            $.each(tempArray, function (k, value) {
                result.push(value);
            });
        } else if (!$.isNumeric(obj[key]) && prop == key && obj[key].toLowerCase().match(val)) {
            result.push(passName + '["' + obj[prop] + '"]');
        } else {
            if ($.isNumeric(obj[prop])) {
                //passName += ' > ' + obj[prop];
            } else {
                passName += '["' + obj[prop] + '"]';
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Which will return

```
["Categories"]["Product2"]["b03"]
```