# Get object key path by value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to get the path of a property based on a value put into a function. I've searched high and low, and the reverse is easily acheivable `(_.pluck)`. It would work something like this:

given

```
var myObj = {
  some: {
    thing: 'hello'
  },
  other: {
    thing: 'world'
  }
}
```

`getPath(myObj, 'hello');` would return `'some.thing'` or `['some', 'thing']` (array preferably).

Would be awesome if this is flexible for different sized objects too. +points for a lodash solution.

Comment: Please share what you've tried.

Comment: I think you're going to have to create a custom solution to this...see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214798/path-to-matching-key-value-pair-in-a-nested-object) for a good start

Answer (score 0):

This works only two levels deep, a quick solution:

```
function getPath (obj, name) {
    var location = null;

    for (var lvl_1 in obj) {
        if (obj[lvl_1] === name) {
            location = lvl_1;
            return location;
        } else if (typeof obj[lvl_1] === 'object') {
            for (var lvl_2 in obj[lvl_1]) {
                if (obj[lvl_1][lvl_2] === name) {
                    location = lvl_1 + '.' + lv;_2;
                    return location;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return location;
}
```

I ran this with your variables

> > `getPath(myObj, 'hello')`
>
> `"some.thing"`

If you want an array, split it:

> > `getPath(myObj, 'hello').split('.')`
>
> `["some", "thing"]`